Etymology of まで?
Is anything known about the etymology of particle まで? What is its derivation? Is it known to be composed of any other morphemes, or are any related words known?

Adding on to Arfrever's post.
Where does made come from?
The word made is attested since at least the Man'yōshū poetry collection, completed around 759.  This word has been around for just about the entirety of the history of written Japanese.
I see that the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 (NKD) entry here at Kotobank includes a 迄の語誌 section towards the bottom.  This explains:

( 1 )語源は両手の意の体言であろうとされ、「万葉集」中「まで」が「二手・左右手・諸手」と表記されているのは語源意識の反映かという。その他「まだし・貧し・惑ふ」と同源で、不十分の意から到達・波及の意となったもの〔改撰標準日本文法=松下大三郎〕、「目処(まと)」即ち「的」と同義〔弖爾乎波の原理的研究=新井無二郎〕などの説がある。
(1) The etymology is deemed to be a nominal meaning "both hands", and the spellings for まで seen in the Man'yōshū as 二手 [normal reading futate, "two hands"], 左右手 [normal reading unclear: hidari migi te? sayū te?, "left and right hands"], and 諸手 [normal reading morote, "both hands"] might be reflective of an awareness of the etymology.  Other theories suggest cognacy with まだし [madashi, "premature, not yet"], 貧し [madoshi, "insufficient, poor"], and 惑ふ [classical madofu, modern madou, "be confused, be puzzled, vacillate"], from the idea of "not enough" then leading to a meaning of "arrival" or "reaching" (as in the Revised Selection, Standard Japanese Grammar by Daizaburō Matsushita); or cognacy with 目処 [mato, literally "eye place"], in other words 的 [mato, "target"] (as in Fundamental Research on "Te Ni O Wa" [particles] by Munirō? Bujirō? Arai).

Possibly related word
Separately, I note the existence of the word 真手 (mate) meaning "both hands".
Phonetic spelling in the Man'yōshū
Digging around in the text of the Man'yōshū on my own (I've got a local copy, also accessible here via the University of Virginia's now-archived "Japanese Text Initiative"), I see various cases where the word まで is spelled phonetically in man'yōgana as mate instead, such as 麻天 (mate) in poem 9.1706, or 麻弖 (mate) in poems 9.1809, 3.485, and 20.4326.  This would be consistent with the term originally being mate as a compound with 手 (te), with voicing happening later due possibly to the influence of the nasal /m/ at the start of the word.  We also see the phonetic spelling made, such as 麻而 (made) in poem 8.1507, or 麻提 (made) in poem 5.839, possibly suggesting that the shift from mate to made was in process at the time these poems were written down.
Semantic spelling in the Man'yōshū
There are also many places in the Man'yōshū where the word is spelled ideographically as 左右, reinforcing the interpretation that the underlying sense of the word was "both hands" (not least as these characters in Chinese originally referred to "left hand" and "right hand"), such as in the line 見左右二 (glossed in modernized texts as miru made ni) in poem 8.1420.
Conclusion: grammatically a noun, likely 真手
If this is derivationally the compound noun 真手, this would fit the grammatical and syntactic analysis of Vovin quoted in Arfrever's post.  Consider the line in poem 4.485:









Original man'yōgana
日乃久流留麻弖


Hiragana
ひのくるるまて


Modern spelling
日の暮れるまで



The use of the 連体形【れんたけい】 or adnominal conjugation くるる grammatically tells us that the following word is probably a noun, again consistent with Vovin.
→ From what I've seen, modern made looks like a possible derivation from 真手 (mate), originally meaning "both hands" and used lexically with a sense more like "reach, extent", as if one reaches out with both hands to show the extent of something.

Thank you so much for the detailed and informative answer!

Alexander Vovin (2020, "A Descriptive and Comparative Grammar of Western Old Japanese", pages 196-197, 199):

1.2.2.13 Terminative Case Marker -maⁿde
The terminative case marker -maⁿde indicates the limit of a movement or another action in time or space, or in other words, the point beyond which the action does not reach. It must be noted that -maⁿde can be followed by the locative case marker -ni, with no apparent change in meaning. This usage predominantly occurs with -maⁿde-ni used after a nominalized clause (see below), although there are two examples of the same usage after a noun. That differs from the modern Japanese double case marker -made-ni, which expresses a terminative-directive meaning ‘by,’ as in getsuyōbi-made-ni ‘by Monday.’
(…)
Similar to the case markers -wo, -ni and -yuri/-yo/-yori, -maⁿde can also mark a nominalized clause, meaning ‘until.’ It is interesting that in the oldest Old Japanese texts the terminative case marker -maⁿde occurs only after a nominalized sentence, and not after a noun, like in the following two examples from the Nihonshoki kayō and the Bussoku seki no uta. Besides, even in the later texts from the Man’yōshū, its usage after a nominalized clause occurs much more frequently than after a noun (with a ratio almost 3:1). Yamada Yoshio suggested that -maⁿde might be originally an adverb (Yamada 1954: 474); however the more frequent and ancient usage after nominalized clauses rather points to the fact that -maⁿde is originally some kind of a bound noun. Its etymology is obscure.
(…)
In Eastern Old Japanese the terminative case marker -maⁿde occurs only after nominalized sentences. This probably represents another piece of evidence for the innovative nature of the use of -maⁿde after nouns.

